# Where is the official documentation for the files in /usr/share/pam-configs, in Ubuntu?

Tags: debian, pam

I'm trying to add some configuration to PAM in Ubuntu, and I'd like to do it using a file in /usr/share/pam-configs. Is there an official documentation for those files?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The canonical place for PAM configuration framework specification is [PAMConfigFrameworkSpec](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/PAMConfigFrameworkSpec).

Comment: Am I the only one who feels unmoored by the fact that one of the most critical privilege elevation managers for the entire *NIX shared ecosystem has _extremely_ sparse documentation after a dozen years in service? To the point that when people ask for more information, the best available answer is a modest treatment replete with draft undertones on a semi-abandoned MoinMoin wiki that hasn't seen a single edit in over a decade?

To be clear this isn't criticism, I believe this is the best available answer, I've just wished that it wasn't for several years now.

Answer (score -1):

`man pam.conf` brings up the manual page for pam config files.

Answer (score -1):

Try `man pam-auth-update`, that's the program managing `/etc/pam.d/common-*` according to these descriptions.